# d3.js maps: using a geojson file AND CSV data

Tags: csv, d3.js, data-binding, geojson

I'm having trouble getting a map in d3.js to respond to data held in a csv (or tsv). I'm working with a geojson file and have been successful in showing the county boundaries in Illinois. The map, however, does not respond to data in the tsv file.

I suspect that the problem may be where I bind the data -- data() -- to the path. Mark Bostock uses
`.data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)`, but that's based on a function structure I don't fully understand: `function ready([us])`  I suspect that the line of my code that's problematic is `.data(values[0].features, values[population])`

Here is the entirety of my code, which produces a map of Illinois counties but nothing else. I've stripped down the data to just be fill colors for troubleshooting purposes.

My json file is available here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cyrusobrien/cyrusobrien/master/documents/illinois_ods.geojson and the data is here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cyrusobrien/cyrusobrien/master/html/countytest.tsv

Apologies for not posting on jfiddle, but (I think) I'm having domain conflict issues there.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My map</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <style></style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" class="svg-container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var w = 900;
    var h = 500;
    var svg = d3.select("div#container").append("svg").attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet").style("background-color","#c9e8fd")
        .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + w + " " + h)
        .classed("svg-content", true);

    // load data

    var population = d3.map();


    var promises = [
        d3.json("/documents/illinois_ods.geojson"),
        d3.tsv("/html/countytest.tsv", function(d) { population.set(d.NAME, +d.color); })];



    var projection = d3.geoMercator().translate([w/2, h/2]).scale(2900).center([-89.3985,40.6331]);
    var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

//draw map
    Promise.all(promises).then(function(values){
        svg.selectAll("path")
            .data(values[0].features, values[population])
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("fill",function (d) {d.color = population.get(d.NAME); })
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If it's relevant, I'm running this on my local machine using webstorm and jekyll.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Loading data

`Promise.all()` returns an array of fulfilled promises. To use them, you can access them directly from the values array.

One convenient thing to do is [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Op%C3%A9rateurs/Affecter_par_d%C3%A9composition): this is what Bostock does with his `function ready([us])`. In this case, you could do something like:

```js
Promise.all(promises).then(function([illinois, data]){
    enter code here
});
```

## Manipulating data

In your code, it seems what you're trying to do is use `data()` for the two datasets at the same time, which doesn't work in D3. We can merge the two datasets with a loop that finds the associated "part" of Illinois by name in the GeoJSON, and appends the associated data.

Afterwards, you only manipulate one data: the `illinois` data that has been merged.

```js
const parts = illinois.features
parts.forEach(geoJsonObject => {
  const linkedData = data.find(d => d === geoJsonObject.name)
  geoJsonObject.properties.data = linkedData
})
// .. use illinois, access data with properties.data:
svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(illinois.features)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", path)
  .attr("fill", d => d.properties.data.color)
```

Putting everything in the `data` property is a little heavy handed right now, but I assume you've got other data than color. If not, feel free to append color directly to the object.